# Passing integer parameter into an ORDER BY clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server that calculates a moving average like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calcMA (@value_name AS varchar(100),
                         @period AS INT,
                         @col1 AS varchar(100),
                         @col2 AS varchar(100))

    WITH CTE_MA (DT, RowNumber, MA) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            DT,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DT ASC) RowNumber,
            AVG(LSTPX) OVER (ORDER BY DT ASC ROWS 9 PRECEDING) AS MA
        FROM 
            dbo.myDb
        WHERE 
            Col1 = @Col1 AND Col2 = @Col2
    )
    SELECT 
        @value_name AS Name, DT,
        IIF (RowNumber > @period - 1, MA, NULL) AS 'Value' 
    FROM 
        CTE_MA
```

The problem I'm running into is that I want the `@period` parameter to be used in place of the number 9 in the `ORDER BY` clause, however, I am finding this difficult to accomplish.

If I try `ORDER BY DT ASC ROWS @period -1 PRECEDING` or `ORDER BY DT ASC ROWS (@period - 1) PRECEDING`, I get syntax errors.

The questions on SO that I read about this have a text variable that's used in the `ORDER BY` clause, which necessitates a `CASE` expression, but I haven't seen an answer about how to enter a continuous number.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The window frame has to be defined by literals, not a variable (as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). You can't use a variable to define the window frame; you would have to go down the dynamic SQL route.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want using `apply`:

```
with d as (
      select d.*, row_number() over (order by dt) as seqnum
      from db.mydb
      where Col1 = @Col1 and Col2 = @Col2
     )
select d.*, dd.avg_lstpx
from d cross apply
     (select avg(d2.LSTPX) as avg_lstpx
      from d d2
      where d2.col1 = d.col1 and d2.col2 = d.col2 and
            d2.seqnum >= d.seqnum - @period
            d2.seqnum <= d.seqnum
     ) dd
```